# How do I make an element scale down to nothing using a CSS transition on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, css, animation, safari, webkit

I’m trying to use the proprietary iPhone Safari properties `-webkit-transition` and `-webkit-transform` to make an element disappear with a graceful animation. Code:

```
<div id="right" style="font-size: 500%; text-align: center; background-color: #fdf; -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform; -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;">3</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function shrinky() {
        this.style.webkitTransform = 'scale(0,1)';
    }

    document.getElementById('right').onclick = shrinky;
</script>
```

I’d expect the element to shrink down to invisible with a graceful animation.

This works fine on desktop Safari (3.2.1 (5525.27.1) on OS X 10.5.6), but on the iPhone (iPhone OS 2.2.1 (5H11)), the `div` just disappears abruptly.

Is there any way to make the animation work like [Apple’s documentation (registration required, I think)](https://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariVisualEffectsProgGuide/Transitions/chapter_5_section_1.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008032-CH4-SW1) says it should?

Comment: just to let you know that your original code (the one in the question) works normal as you can see it in a simple screencast: http://is.gd/xk7H

Comment: Sure, sorry, I should have been clearer: the code works fine in desktop Safari, it’s Safari on the iPhone that seems to have the problem.

Great job with the screencast though, talk about clarity. I bet a lot of Stack Overflow answers could benefit from a bit of video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the first `scale` argument to a very small decimal, rather than 0, seems to make the animation work. Code:

```
<div id="right" style="font-size: 500%; text-align: center; background-color: #fdf; -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform; -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;">3</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function shrinky() {
        this.style.webkitTransform = 'scale(0.000001,1)';
    }

    document.getElementById('right').onclick = shrinky;
</script>
```

Not sure if this is an iPhone bug or not, but it seems like it.